# change the soap:address location in generated wsdl

Tags: web-services, soap, jax-ws, jboss5.x

I am using JAX-WS annotation to create soap services running on JBOss 5.1.0 G.A, the generates WSDL has got the following bit at the end -

```
<service name="DataServiceService">
 <port binding="tns:DataServiceBinding" name="DataServicePort">
  <soap:address location="http://mymachine:8080/myapp/webservice" /> 
  </port>
  </service>
```

I have made the service https enabled on port 8443, I am able to connect to the service using the right protocol and port number but is there is a way to change the soap address in the generated wsdl so that the clients don't have to change it?

I would like to see the address as

```
<soap:address location="https://mymachine:8443/myapp/webservice" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment the following line in
server/{instance}/deployers/jbossws.deployer/META-INF/jboss-beans.xml

```
<property name="webServiceHost">${jboss.bind.address}</property>
```

This way the engine should rewrite the soap:address using the host/port used to invoke the servlet providing you the wsdl.