# Spring Generated WSDL exposes wrong protocol (HTTP vs HTTPS) endpoint location

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wsdl, reverse-proxy

I have a Tomcat server running "behind" an Apache 2 (via mod_proxy), in the Tomcat there is a WAR serving Spring generated Webservices, which expose a service like this one:

```
<wsdl:service name="EcoboxPortService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:EcoboxPortSoap11" name="EcoboxPortSoap11">
        <soap:address location="http://host:80/ecobox-ws/Ecobox"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

The problem is that the WSDL is actually obtained by the following URL:

```
https://host/ecobox-ws/ecobox.wsdl (Please note it uses HTTPS)
```

Given the above 2 questions arise:

1. Why does the WSDL add the '80' port to the endpoint location? Can it be overridden?
2. Why does it get 'http' protocol, despite the actual URL requested was via 'https'? Doesn't Spring interpret 'X-forwarded-for' headers?

Similar question, but not entirely helpful: [change the soap:address location in generated wsdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21479854/change-the-soapaddress-location-in-generated-wsdl)

Relevant dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Relevant web.xml excerpt:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Is your server (tomcat and or Apache) enabled to serve resources in HTTP? It seems to me something more related to tomcat. Is your web application able in serving resources in HTTP?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata yes, actually Tomcat is only configured for HTTP, but Apache for both

Comment: When you try to display the WSDL by typing URL http://..... did you check if you are redirect in https? If so... it's something related to Apache configuration. Another check you could do is to access to the WSDL directly (maybe a wget on the server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your Tomcat configuration, where you'd need to set  "proxyName" and "proxyPort". 
JAX-WS auto-generation should pick it up from there / the request-headers.
More information here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

Comment: I like that approach, I'll see what I get by tweaking those values, but at first glance I can see that I can guide Tomcat to expose port 443 instead of 80, but what about the protocol? It would still be reporting http instead of https, am I right?

Comment: just missed the "schema" attribute forced into "https", with the proxyPort in 443 and that did the trick...great answer!

Comment: Always happy to help, had a similar issue using nginx w/ spring-boot not too long ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/server.html#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure)

You need to tell the MessageDispatherServlet to transform the location:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Or if you use Java Config

> If you use the
>   AbstractAnnotationConfigMessageDispatcherServletInitializer, enabling
>   transformation is as simple as overriding the
>   isTransformWsdlLocations() method to return true.

Comment: It's already configured that way, at least it's preserving the "external" hostname, but not the protocol, nor the port.